# There exists a unique measure $\mu$ such that $\mu([a,b]) = b^2-a^2$

Tags: measure-theory

I have the following question about measure theory:

> Show that there's a single measure $\mu$ on Borel $\sigma$-Algebra, such that for all $a<b$, if $a \ge 0$ than $\mu([a,b]) = b^2-a^2$, and if $b \leq 0$, than $\mu([a,b]) = 0$.

I've asked my tutor about this, and she said that we want to prove the existence and uniqueness of a measure that gives a certain value to finite open intervals. 
I assume that this is the same idea as the proof of the existence and uniqueness of the Lebesgue measure, i.e. to define a specific outer measure and define the measure from that, however it seems a bit cumbersome to me. 
I would really like some hint on this, I'm quite stumped.

Comment: Maybe Carathéodory's extension theorem works in this case?

Comment: I don't think I've learned about this theorem. What does this theorem state, and how it could be used in this question?

Comment: Hint: What is $\int_a^b 2x dx$?

Comment: I also don't think I can use measures defined by integrals, as we have not reached that subject yet. I can only use concepts regarding Lebesgue measure and outer measure.